# probability that no two people are born on the same day: $n$ people and $k$ days

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

Say we have $n$ people and $k$ days. What is the probability that NO two of the $n$ people are born on the same day?

This is of course assuming that $n \leq k$ (otherwise the answer is $0$ by the pigeonhole principle!).
I said the answer was: $k \choose n$$\cdot n! \cdot \frac{1}{k^n}$ because in order for this to happen, n *distinct* birthdays must be chosen, they can be arranged in any way amongst the $n$ people, and there are $k^n$ total arrangements. Is this correct?

Comment: Your answer appears correct to me. A good way to make sure of this would be to check for small values of $n$ and $k$ that you could count all the possible outcomes by hand and solve the probability that way and see if your formula simplifies to the same answer.

Comment: This is the well-known "birthday problem".  Your answer appears to be correct.  Also if $n > k$ your formula still holds, because then ${k \choose n}$ is zero by definition.

Comment: Thank you both! Didn't realize it's a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ${k \choose n} \cdot n! \cdot \frac{1}{k^n}$ is correct assuming equal independent probabilities for each day and person

To illustrate it with $k=365$, you get

- with $n=22$, the probability the birthdays are all different of about $0.5243047$
- with $n=23$, the probability the birthdays are all different of about $0.4927028$

and so the solution to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) that the median number of people to have at least one matching birthday is $23$